# How can I give appropriate icons in HTML tag using object values in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements, react-props

I'm having trouble allocating right icon signs to tags, using values of objects.

please check my code first.

```js
// index.js
// I just made this code, so there might be misspelling.

const DATA = [
  {
    question: what is the name of the inventor?,
    a: Mark,
    b: Jacob,
    c: Aden,
    d: Morrie,
    answer: a,
    userAnswer: c
  },
  {
    question: what is the most favorite sports in United States?,
    a: Golf,
    b: Soccer,
    c: Football,
    d: Basketball,
    answer: c,
    userAnswer: a
  },
]

const index = () => {
    const wrongQuestions = DATA.map((answer) => (
    <WrongAnswerLayout props={answer} key={answer.question} />
  ))

  return (
    <ul>
      {wrongQuestions}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

```js
// WrongAnswerLayout.js

const WrongAnswerLayout = ({ props }) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <div>{props.question}</div>
      <p>{props.a}</p>
      <p>{props.b}</p>
      <p>{props.c}</p>
      <p>{props.d}</p>
      <p>userAnswer {props.userAnswer}</p>
    </li>
  )
}
```

and finally, I have,

```js
import { Correct, Incorrect, Normal } from 'assets/svgs'
```

which are the icons that signs correct answer, incorrect user answer, and just questions.

[image]

It looks like this.

**However, what I'm trying to do is using `DATA.answer` and `DATA.userAnswer`, I want to give appropriate icons to tags.**

For example. for the `DATA[1]`, `Incorrect Sign` should be placed next to Golf (which was user's answer but not the actual answer), and `Correct Sign` should be placed next to Football. Moreover, other choices should be next to `<Normal />` component.

I'm having trouble figuring out this problem. Please give me some guidance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over all the options and conditionally display the appropriate icon.

```js
const DATA = [
  { question: "What is the name of the inventor?", a: "Mark", b: "Jacob", c: "Aden", d: "Morrie", answer: "a", userAnswer: "c" },
  { question: "What is the most favorite sports in United States?", a: "Golf", b: "Soccer", c: "Football", d: "Basketball", answer: "c", userAnswer: "a" },
];

const App = () => (
  <ul>
    {DATA.map((ques) => (
      <WrongAnswerLayout ques={ques} key={ques.question} />
    ))}
  </ul>
);

const WrongAnswerLayout = ({ ques }) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <p><strong>{ques.question}</strong></p>
      <ol>
        {["a", "b", "c", "d"].map((opt) => (
          <li key={opt}>
            {ques[opt]}{" "}
            {ques.answer === opt && <i className="fa-solid fa-check" />}
            {ques.answer !== ques.userAnswer && ques.userAnswer === opt && (
              <i className="fa-solid fa-xmark" />
            )}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ol>
      <p>User's Answer: {ques.userAnswer}</p>
    </li>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div id="root"></div>
```